# Convert MATLAB char array to string

Tags: string, matlab, char

Starting with the MATLAB char array, A:

```
A(1,1) = 'A'
A(1,2) = 'P'
A(1,3) = 'R'
A(2,1) = 'M'
A(2,2) = 'A'
A(2,3) = 'Y'
```

How can this be converted to a cell of strings, B, such that:

```
B{1} = 'APR'
B{2} = 'MAY'
```

Edit:
A is a cell and using the function cellstr gives the error

```
Error using cellstr (line 23)
S must be 2-D.
```

Comment: Who is S in your error message?

Comment: I have A = data{3,1} (some cell data) so that A is now a <2x6 char>. I then enter B = cellstr(A) and I get the error.

Comment: Can you put the data in the question or on pastebin?

Comment: Also, does cellstr work for A?

Comment: In trying to paste my data I seemed to have found a solution. Initially my data was pairs of months in a <2106x2x6 char>, T say. I then tried cellstr(T(1,:,:)) resulting in the above error. However when I assigned A(:,:) = T(1,:,:) and did cellstr(A), it worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html

```
>> B =  cellstr(A)

B = 

    'APR'
    'MAY'

>> B{1}

ans =

APR
```

Answer (score 2):

For a 3D char array T

```
B = cellstr(T(1,:,:))
```

Gives the error

```
Error using cellstr (line 23)
S must be 2-D.
```

Instead assign it to a 2D matrix first, then use 'cellstr' as Franck suggested above.

```
A(:,:) = T(1,:,:)
B = cellstr(A)
```